# Azure Devops Agent Performance

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I've  an Azure Devops Services ( currently i've two project with one hosted agent only ), and i've NPM step in our build definition, which executes the install command. The build `npm run build --prod`  has slowed to over an hour.

I think , the problem is in the Azure Agent

can you pls show me , how i can tune up this agent or clear the cache of this agent ?

**EDIT :**

in my on-premise environment , the build take over a 20 mins.

In Azure Devops Services , the pipeline fails after 1 hour.

This is the logs :

```
    ##[warning]Ubuntu-latest pipelines will use Ubuntu-20.04 soon. For more details, see https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/1816
    ,##[error]The job running on agent Hosted Agent ran longer than the maximum time of 60 minutes. For more information, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077134
    Pool: Azure Pipelines


> ng build --prod --aot --sm

##[debug]Re-evaluate condition on job cancellation for step: 'Build Solution'.
##[debug]Started cancellation of executing script
##[debug]Exit code null received from tool '/bin/bash'
##[error]The operation was canceled.
##[debug]System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Util.ProcessInvoker.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, InputQueue`1 redirectStandardIn, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, Boolean keepStandardInOpen, Boolean highPriorityProcess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.ProcessInvokerWrapper.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, InputQueue`1 redirectStandardIn, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, Boolean keepStandardInOpen, Boolean highPriorityProcess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Handlers.DefaultStepHost.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Handlers.NodeHandler.RunAsync()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.TaskRunner.RunAsync()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.StepsRunner.RunStepAsync(IStep step, CancellationToken jobCancellationToken)
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more details. What is the performance like if you run the build outside Azure Devops Services? Is there anything interesting in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

There is a recently event of availability degradation of Azure DevOps, which could affected these services, and it has been resolved now. This could affect customers in Europe. If you want to know more information, please click here: https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/228998388

> We are noticing increased load across Europe region and we are trying
> to increase capacity to handle additional load. We will continue to
> monitor and update once the issue mitigates.

[image]